# To run G-WAN, you must fix the error(s) or remove this Servlet

Tags: c, g-wan

I am using gwan 7.12.6 on my Ubuntu Server 14.04.4 LTS and I start it with the command `sudo service gwan test` that is equivalent to the command `sudo ./gwan` (so not in deamon mode).

Then, all the servlets compile without any error, but `kv_bench.c` and `auth_oauth.c`.

When removing the undercore charater of these two servlets, gwan dies with the message:

> To run G-WAN, you must fix the error(s) or remove this Servlet.

What is wrong with these two servlets (I'm not a C specialist) that are included with the standard gwan distribution?

Answer (score 0):

The file extension of some C servlets begin with an underscore ("*._c") to disable them at startup.

This is done because these scripts rely on C `libraries` that may not be available on people's machine. This is mentioned in the servlet file, along with the library name that is required (#pragma link "...").

When you rename these servlets to activate them, these servlets compile but fail to link as the necessary dependencies are missing... hence the error message *"To run G-WAN, you must fix the error(s) or remove this Servlet"*.

As the `G-WAN PDF manual` explains all this, I suggest you to have a look at it.